# Shuffle list except for certain sequences

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to shuffle an `ArrayList` but based on some custom conditions: 
if my array list was something like `[1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 45, 67]`,
I want to shuffle it but make sure `5, 6, 9` always appear together.

Is there any method available in `Collections` class to do this?

I have tried doing this, but it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
 List<Integer> y= new ArrayList<>();
 y.add(1);
 y.add(4);
 y.add(5);
 y.add(6);
 y.add(9);
 y.add(45);
 y.add(67);
 List<Integer> z = y.subList(2, 5);
 y.removeAll(z);
 Collections.shuffle(y);
 int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                              .nextInt(0, y.size() + 1);
 y.addAll(index,z);
```

Comment: no..you need to write your custom shuffle function.

Comment: doubt it. you are looking for a very specific rule, which sort of goes against all the rest of the elements. Pretty sure the inventors of Java didn't have an "we need to keep 5, 6 and 9 always together" mindset

Comment: *"we need to keep 5, 6 and 9 always together" mindset* - LOL

Comment: Take out `5,6,9`, shuffle the list, put it back

Comment: thanks for the humor guys, i was expecting help not this.
@ThumChoonTat what if i had multiple such groups?

Comment: Use another array list to store the groups would do. After shuffle put each group back into the list

Comment: when you say put, i would need to randomize that too, that is where i am having issues

Comment: i have added a little code of what i tried

Comment: Your code is wrong even if there is no exception thrown. ` y.removeAll(z);` will remove all 5,6,9 even if there are not neighbors.

Comment: @user6690200: yes i wanted to remove them and shuffle, whats wrong in that?

Comment: @Bhargav  If your array is `1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 45, 67, 5`, you will lost the end element 5 with `removeAll`. It will not be put back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your data should really be a list of lists, especially since its likely that you will have more than 1 group that needs to stay together.
You can always flatten it when you need.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> y = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        y.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1)));
        y.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4)));
        y.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 6, 9)));
        y.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(45)));
        y.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(67)));
        Collections.shuffle(y);
        List<Integer> flatList = new ArrayList<>();
        y.forEach(flatList::addAll);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this is to store your target elements in a *separate* `List`:

```
List<Integer> target = new ArrayList<>();
target.add(5);
target.add(6);
target.add(9);
```

Then shuffle your main list:

```
Collections.shuffle(y);
```

Then get a random number from `0` -> `y.size()`.

```
Random ran = new Random();
int pos = ran.nextInt(y.size());
```

And insert your target list into your original list:

```
y.addAll(pos, target);
```

<sup>**Note:** this assumes your original list has the target 3 numbers removed already.</sup>

Comment: Hi, i have tried the same thing almost. But was wondering what if there are multiple such target groups?

Comment: Also i get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at the addAll line

Comment: thats because you are not doing the "note" part. 
try doing this then you will get that y.removeAll(z);

Comment: If you wrap **every** element in its own list, and keep the grouped elements together in the same lists, you end up with a list of lists, which you can shuffle and then flatten again. `List -> groupd & wrap -> List<List> -> shuffle -> flatten -> List`

Comment: @MalteHartwig wow, that does sound good, can you help me with implementation

Comment: @Bhargav then don't use `y.subList(2, 5);` and just create your target List manually.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I'd think that the `ConcurrentModificationException`s are thrown because you try to remove the group elements from the list or to add them back in while iterating it. Changing a collection while iterating it leads to those exceptions: [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re).

It will get a lot easier if you do not treat the groups as the exception, but as the norm. What I mean by this is that you should convert your `List<?>` into a `List<List<?>>` where each sub list contains either one element or one of the groups. You can then shuffle that list easily with `Collections.shuffle()` and flatten it again.

Look at this rough implementation:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(asList(2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 7, 11, 55));
List<List<Integer>> groups = asList(asList(5, 4), asList(7, 11));

// remove all the grouped elements from the list
groups.forEach(ints::removeAll);

// wrap the single elements into list and join them with the groups
List<List<Integer>> wrapped = Stream.concat(ints.stream().map(Arrays::asList),
                                            groups.stream())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Collections.shuffle(wrapped);

// flatten the list into single elements again
List<Integer> shuffled = wrapped.stream()
                                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(shuffled); // e.g. [55, 3, 7, 11, 2, 8, 5, 4]
                              //              -----        ----
```

Note that while this is quite readable, it is probably not the most efficient or error proof solution. But it should give you an idea how to tackle the problem.

---

Edit after comment from Gonen I. Here is a helper method to only remove the exact sequences and not random parts of them all over the list:

```
private static <T> void removeSequence(List<T> list, List<T> sequence)
{
    int indexOfSubList = Collections.lastIndexOfSubList(list, sequence);
    while (indexOfSubList != -1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sequence.size(); j++)
        {
            list.remove(indexOfSubList);
        }
        indexOfSubList = Collections.lastIndexOfSubList(list, sequence);
    }
}
```

Use it by replacing `groups.forEach(ints::removeAll);` by `groups.forEach(group -> removeSequence(ints, group));`

Comment: cool, nice job. You could use Collections.indexOfSublist to simplify

Comment: @GonenI thanks for the great hint! I didn't know that one yet, guess I don't look at `Collections` often enough. Especially that they move some stuff to `Collection` directly.